# Adding headers to the websocket handshake response on Java

Tags: java, websocket, cors, handshake

I want to use the data from my WebSocket in the JS app in a browser, but it is resulting into the "GET has been blocked by CORS policy" error.
The websocket written with javax lib. To run I use the tyrus server.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        final Server server = new Server("0.0.0.0", port, "/", null, LiveWebSocket.class);
        try {
            server.start();
            System.out.println("WebSocketServer started on port " + port);
        } catch (final DeploymentException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to start WebSocketServer", e);
        }

        try {
            Thread.currentThread().join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I don't really understand how to add the ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") header to the handshake response, so I can use it with different domains.

I tried to use ContainerResponseFilter

```
@Provider
    public class CorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
    }
}
```

that have been added to the ResourceConfig

```
final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.register(CorsFilter.class);
        config.register(LiveWebSocket.class);
```

but I don't know how to integrate this into the server.

I want to run the socket from my main method and don't want to use proxy servers to handle the connection. Does anybody have an idea around it?

Comment: CORS doesn't apply to WebSockets.

Comment: So, there is no way to handle the error on the server side? In this case, is the proxy server the only way?